# Лучший способ сделать мобильную версию сайта на Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, mobile

Поделитесь опытом, у кого есть. Мобильная версия сильно отличается от десктопной. У меня есть несколько вариантов, как сделать мобильную версию, и я не могу решить, как будет лучше и проще. Как вы делали мобильные версии на битриксе?

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Для повторного открытия, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

Comment: Интересно почему этот вопрос всплыл спустя столько времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как никто мне не ответил, я нашел способ сам и отвечу сам себе - 
Я сделал мобильную версию как отдельный шаблон, который подключается в админке `(Настройки -> Настройки продукта -> Сайты -> Список сайтов -> Редактирование сайта -> раздел Шаблон )` по такому условию:

```
[Мобильный шаблон][сортировка больше обычного шаблона][Выражение PHP] -> [preg_match("/(ipad|iphone|android|operamobi|blackberry)/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);]
```

Про то,как я делал сам шаблон с мобильной версией,распространятся не буду,т.к. вопрос был не об этом.

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас стоит тот же вопрос. Я его решаю с помощью адаптивного дизайна: тот же шаблон, но плюс дополнительные стили с соответствующими @media (@media screen and (max-width:750px), handheld and (max-width:750px) и т.п.). Этот вариант подходит, если:

1. Вы ничего против адаптивного дизайна не имеете
2. Структура мобильной версии и обычной резко не отличается

Если такой вариант не подходит, можно:

- Делать как предложили вы
- Если структура будет совсем разная, то дублировать контент...

Comment: Вы правильно угадали, почему я не воспользовался этим вариантом - макеты кардинально отличались друг от друга,в мобильной версии было гораздо меньше страниц и немного отличный набор категорий товаров (некоторые категории были объединены в более общие) .